# std::map with only move constructor available

Tags: c++

I have a class with private constructor (that my container class can access), deleted copy constructor, and default move constructor. How can I use it in a `std::map`?

```
class Item {
public:
    Item(const Item&) = delete;
private:
    friend class Storage;
    Item(int value);
};

class Storage {
public:
    void addItem(int key, int value) {
        // what to put here?
    }
private:
    std::map<int, Item> items_;
};
```

Using `emplace(key, Item(value))` doesn't work, because it tries to copy construct the item. Wrapping Item in `std::move` has the same effect. Using `piecewise_construct` doesn't work because the map (or pair) tries to use normal constructor, which is private.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have a class with private constructor (that my container class can access), deleted copy constructor, and default move constructor.

Wrong, you do not have a defaulted move constructor. You don't get an implicit move constructor if you declare a copy constructor. You'll need to explicitly default the move constructor to get one:

```
class Item {
public:
    Item(const Item&) = delete;
    Item(Item&&) = default;

    // Might be a good idea to declare the two assignment operators too
    Item& operator=(const Item&) = delete;
    Item& operator=(Item&&) = default;
private:
    friend class Storage;
    Item(int value);
};
```

Now you can use:

```
items_.emplace(key, Item(value));
```

for example to insert an entry.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize the difference. Works perfectly now with either form. Emplace is probably better in your example, though?

Comment: You may want to also `= delete` copy assignment and `= default` move assignment.

Comment: Fair enough, though the map doesn't seem to need move assignment so I'll just disable the copy.